# Linear approximation of expected value

Tags: taylor-expansion, expected-value, approximation, linear-approximation

I am reading a paper where there is an approximation of an expected value.  I am not sure what sort of approximation method they are using.  Reminds me a bit of Taylors Theorem, but I am just not connecting the dots.

\begin{align*}
P(XC + \sqrt{X}A + B \leq z) = & E\left [I(XC + \sqrt{X}A + B \leq z)\right] \\
= &   E\left [I(XC \leq z)\right] + E\left [I'\right]A + O(E(A^2)) + O(E|AB|) + O(EB) \\
\end{align*}

where

- $I' = \frac{\partial}{\partial A} P(XC +
     \sqrt{X}A + B \leq Z) $ evaluated at $A= 0$, $B=0$, and $C=C$
- $I(\cdot\leq Z)$ is the indicator function
- $X, A, B, C$ all have random components

Comment: What is $A$? It's not in the original expression

Comment: It is fixed now.